# Better way to do a few save in one tranaction in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, transactions

Here is our code to save quite a few objects all at once within one transaction. What the code does is to create a new checkout record (for warehouse) and update each item (there may be a few of them) in stock. Since all save has to be either all or none, we put all the save within Rails `transaction`:

```
  @checkout = RequisitionCheckoutx::Checkout.new(params[:checkout])
  @checkout.last_updated_by_id = session[:user_id]
  @checkout.checkout_by_id = session[:user_id]
  @checkout.transaction do
    params['ids'].each do |id| 
      params['out_qtys'].each do |qty| #ids passed in as a string of 'id'
        stock_item = RequisitionCheckoutx.warehouse_class.find_by_id(id.to_i)
        qty = qty.to_i
        if stock_item.stock_qty >= qty
          stock_item.stock_qty = stock_item.stock_qty - qty
          stock_item.last_updated_by_id = session[:user_id]
          begin
            stock_item.save
          rescue => e
            flash[:notice] = t('Stock Item#=') + id.to_s  + ',' + e.message
          end
        end
      end unless params['out_qtys'].blank?
    end unless params['ids'].blank? 
    if @checkout.save 
      redirect_to URI.escape(SUBURI + "/authentify/view_handler?index=0&msg=Successfully Saved!")
    else
      flash[:notice] = t('Data Error. Not Saved!')
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

We haven't run the test yet and the code looks not pretty. Is there a better way to handle this kind of batch save? Also should the `rescue` loop be removed for transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transaction` block should be performed first and then you should deal with action response. Besides that, catching exception here is pointless, cause using `save` returns simply true or false. Your transaction should look like:

```
RequisitionCheckoutx::Checkout.transaction do
  begin

  #...
  #...
  stock_item.save! # it will raise RecordInvalid or RecordNotSaved if something goes wrong

  #...
  #...  

  @checkout.save!

  rescue Exception => e
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback # it calls Rollback to the database 
  end
end
```

Now, using `ActiveModel::Dirty` you need to check if `@checkout` has been saved:

```
if !@checkout.changed?
  redirect_to "/something"
 else
  flash[:notice] = t('Data Error. Not Saved!')
  render 'new'
end
```

Comment: @@blelump, if there is one @checkout.save for each stock_item.save, can we still use the same !@checkout.changed? (for redirect or render) ?

Comment: Also how can we rollback and quit the transaction if stock_item.stock_qty >= qty is false?

Comment: ad. 1: No. In this case you should make an array of checkouts and after the transaction, check if all checkouts were saved. Is such case even possible?
ad. 2: Yep, just raise whatever `Exception` you like. `rescue` block will catch it and raise `ActiveRecord::Rollback`

Comment: We may have an array of checkouts to check. Can we check the message (or some other indicator) to determine if there is a rescue and rollback after transaction?

Comment: Well, you can check if all checkouts were persisted, e.g. `checkouts.all? {|checkout| !checkout.changed?}`. You can also define an instance variable within rescue block, e.g. `@transaction_failed = true` and just check for `@transaction_failed` when responding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can we put render 'new' into rescue block (when there is error) and redirect_to after params[:ids] loop (when saves successful)? If this is doable, we can get rid of the checking checkouts.

Comment: Actually you can, however what if transaction was successful? Then controller does not know how to respond.